# How to launch atom installed package - haskell repl and cabal

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

Have installed Haskell atom repl from https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell-repl and also installed cabal package.

How to launch the repl and cabal ?

There does not appear to be an option to open from menu, in same way SublimeText exposes installed packages. Atom probably exposes this functionality differently ?

Here my installed Haskell packages :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Haskell REPL package does not provide a graphical interface for the commands it provides. However, you can call them from the [Command Palette](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#command-palette), one of the central interfaces of editors such as Atom or Sublime Text.

Launch the command palette using the default shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on OS X, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> elsewhere) or from the menu (*Packages > Command Palette > Toggle*) and type any of the commands mentioned in the package's `README.md`. The command palette will also reveal the default [keyboard shortcuts](https://github.com/atom-haskell/ide-haskell-repl/blob/master/keymaps/ide-haskell-repl.cson) for each command.